Unexpected " [] " Characters on Django Admin Log in Page
I have a Django App running on a local server. I am using the default admin features and rendering with collected static files. However, I am seeing " [] " inserted into the main content of the login form.


Why is this and how do I ensure this doesn't occur?

I have just established that this appears to be a known bug related to Python 3.12.4 + Apache + mod_wsgi. Others have experienced the same behaviour. See https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/square-brackets-bug/29632/13 If anyone has a fix I would be interested.
